# i want to calculate sum of leaverequested column month wise

Tags: mysql, sql

```
empid   leavefrom     leaveto      leaverequested    
 1      3/3/2014     4/3/2014       2   
 1      7/3/2014     8/3/2014       2
 1      31/3/2014    1/4/2014       2
 1      10/4/2014    11/4/2014      2
```

I want to calculate the sum of the leaverequested column.

Ouput:

```
march -  5 days
april -  3 days
```

This is my SQL query so far:

```
select Emp_id
  ,datename(month,leave_from) as [First]
  ,datename(month,leave_to) as Last
  ,count(DATEDIFF(Day, leave_from, leave_to)+1) as [Total Leave]
  ,sum(DATEDIFF(Day, leave_from, leave_to)+1) as [Total Days]
from emp_leave
group by Emp_id
        ,datename(month,leave_from)
        ,datename(month,leave_to);
```

Can any one help me to get this output please?

Comment: Why your question is tagged with `mysql` when your code is for SQL Server? These are two different products. Please retag your question appropriately.

Comment: When leave starts in one month and ends in another, which month does it belong to? Do you want to split the days for the sum? What about count?

Comment: when leave starts in one month and end in another month then i want to seperate the leave.like suppose 31/3/2014-1/4/2014 then i want 31 to be consider in march and 1 should be consider in april

Comment: can u please help me with the query and i want total of leaverequested column only because i am calculating the value of leaverequested column by removing sundays and holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about it

```
WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT 0 n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM n WHERE n < 32 -- adjust as needed to max months that a leave can possibly span
), base AS 
( 
  SELECT empid, 
         DATEADD(mm, n.n, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, leavefrom), 0)) basemonth,
         CASE WHEN leavefrom > DATEADD(mm, n.n, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, leavefrom), 0)) 
              THEN leavefrom 
              ELSE DATEADD(mm, n.n, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, leavefrom), 0))
         END sdate, 
         CASE WHEN leaveto < DATEADD(mm, n.n, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, leavefrom) + 1, -1)) 
              THEN leaveto 
              ELSE DATEADD(mm, n.n, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, leavefrom) + 1, -1)) 
         END edate
    FROM emp_leave JOIN n
      ON n.n <= DATEDIFF(month, leavefrom, leaveto)
)
SELECT empid, 
       YEAR(basemonth) year,
       DATENAME(mm, basemonth) month,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(dd, sdate, edate) + 1) total
  FROM base
GROUP BY empid, basemonth
ORDER BY empid, base month
```

Output:

```
| EMPID | YEAR | MONTH | TOTAL |
|-------|------|-------|-------|
|     1 | 2014 | March |     5 |
|     1 | 2014 | April |     3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ee68/21)** demo

Comment: but  thank u so so so so so much for ur kind help.thank u once again.

Comment: sir i want total of leaverequested column because that i am calculating by removing holidays and sundays and your query is working on fromdate and todate.i just want total of leaverequested column month wise.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Now how would you possibly split a single `leaverequested` value in a deterministic fashion across multiple months? You'd probably need to calculate it on the fly.